SQL query use rules for two tables and return results then third table
I'm trying to use rules from 2 tables in sql to add data from a third one, so far I haven't gotten the expected result, it's causing a conflict. Below is an example of the 3 tables and the expected result:
Table Approval



ORÇ
Value
Approval Date




1
R$ 10.000,00
19/07/2024


2
R$ 20.000,00
19/08/2024


3
R$ 30.000,00
20/08/2024



Rule: Orç month 08.
Table FAT



ORÇ
IDFat
Status




1
1X1Y
Cancelado


1
1X2Y



2
2X1Y
Cancelado


2
2X2Y



3
3X1Y



3
3X2Y
Cancelado



Rule: purge IDFat Cancelled.
Table Value



Orçamento
IDFat
Value1
Value2




1
1X1Y
R$ 3.000,00
R$ -


1
1X1Y
R$ -
R$ 7.000,00


1
1X2Y
R$ -
R$ 1.000,00


1
1X2Y
R$ -
R$ 1.000,00


1
1X2Y
R$ -
R$ 1.000,00


1
1X2Y
R$ 3.500,00
R$ -


1
1X2Y
R$ 3.500,00
R$ -


2
2X1Y
R$ 6.000,00
R$ -


2
2X1Y
R$ -
R$ 14.000,00


2
2X2Y
R$ -
R$ 1.500,00


2
2X2Y
R$ -
R$ 1.500,00


2
2X2Y
R$ -
R$ 1.500,00


2
2X2Y
R$ -
R$ 1.500,00


2
2X2Y
R$ 3.500,00
R$ -


2
2X2Y
R$ 3.500,00
R$ -


2
2X2Y
R$ 3.500,00
R$ -


2
2X2Y
R$ 3.500,00
R$ -


3
3X1Y
R$ 9.000,00
R$ -


3
3X1Y
R$ -
R$ 21.000,00


3
3X2Y
R$ -
R$ 3.000,00


3
3X2Y
R$ -
R$ 3.000,00


3
3X2Y
R$ -
R$ 3.000,00


3
3X2Y
R$ 7.000,00
R$ -


3
3X2Y
R$ 7.000,00
R$ -


3
3X2Y
R$ 7.000,00
R$ -



Obs. add the values ​​based on the rules in the previous tables.
Expected Result



Orç
Value
Approval Date
Value1
Value2




2
R$ 20.000,00
19/08/2024
R$ 14.000,00
R$ 6.000,00


3
R$ 30.000,00
20/08/2024
R$ 21.000,00
R$ 9.000,00



Query
select 
    o.Orç,
    o.Value,
    o.Approval_Date,
    fat.Valor1,
    fat.Valor2  
from 
    (
    select
        f.Orç,
        f.Status,
        fx.VALOR1,
        fx.VALOR2
    from
        FAT as f
    left join Value as fx on
        f.IDFat = fx.IDFat
) as fat
left join Approval as o on o.Orç = fat.Orç
where
    fat.Status <> 'C'
    and o.Approval_Date >= '2024-08-01' 
    and o.Approval_Date < '2024-09-01'
 group by o.Orç


Your query doesn't have any tables named Approval, FAT, and Value.

orc01 = Approval, fat02 = FAT, and fat02x == Value? Why are you making it hard for us to figure out what you're doing?

And none of the column names match the columns in your sample data. I can't figure out what is what. What is f.REFERENCIA? You're splitting it by / characters, but there are no columns in that table with that format.

You have tagged this with powerquery. Do you want a powerquery solution or an SQL solution?

@RonRosenfeld I connect the database through powerquery, I'm looking for the best solution, be it in powerquery or sql!

@RobertoTruzzi Please note that, having determined what might be the proper locale settings for R$, I edited the Approval and Value tables pre-processing code for improved efficiency.

Here's one method using Power Query:

Assumptions

You have three separate tables

Approval
FAT
Value


In the Approval and Value tables, you have Typed the Value, Value1, and Value2 columns as number or Currency

In my version, I had to remove the RS$
In the Value table, you replaced the - with null





Edit:Pre-processing of Approval and Value tables made more efficient
Approval
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Approval"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type with Locale" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Source", {
        {"ORÇ",Int64.Type} ,{"Value", Currency.Type},{"Approval Date", type date}}, "pt-BR")
in
    #"Changed Type with Locale"

Value
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Value"]}[Content],
    #"Replaced Value" = 
        Table.ReplaceValue(
            Source,
            "-", 
            null,
            (x,y,z)=> Text.Replace(x,"-","0"), 
            {"Value1","Value2"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Value",{
        {"Orçamento", Int64.Type}, 
        {"IDFat", type text}, 
        {"Value1", Currency.Type}, 
        {"Value2", Currency.Type}},
        "pt-BR")
in
    #"Changed Type"

In the above, change the Source line to reflect your actual data source
Store your conditions someplace. I used a parameter.
This code below will then create your desired output.
let
    #"Included ORÇ" =Table.SelectRows(Approval, each Date.Month([Approval Date]) = #"ORÇ Month"),
    #"Included IDFat" = Table.SelectRows(FAT, 
            each [Status] <> #"FAT Status" and 
            List.ContainsAny(#"Included ORÇ"[ORÇ],{[ORÇ]}))[IDFat],

//Filter the Value table to include only those relevant items from the Approval and FAT tables
    #"Included Value" = Table.SelectRows(Value, each List.ContainsAny(#"Included IDFat",{[IDFat]})),

//Group by ORÇ and SUM the values, also return the approval data
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Included Value", {"Orçamento"}, {
        {"Approval Date", (t)=>Table.SelectRows(#"Included ORÇ", each [ORÇ] = t{0}[Orçamento])[Approval Date]{0}, type date},
        {"Value1", each List.Sum([Value1]), Currency.Type},
        {"Value2", each List.Sum([Value2]), Currency.Type}})
    
in 
    #"Grouped Rows"


